# Covering all except one of the purple intersection points of $n$ red and $m$ blue lines efficiently

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, covering

Consider a set of $n$ red lines and $m$ blue lines, suppose there are $nm$ distinct red-blue intersections.

What is the minimum number of lines $L_1,L_2,\dots, L_n$ such that the union contains all $nm$ intersection points except for exactly one?

A trivial construction is to take $n-1$ red lines and $m-1$ blue lines. I have not been able to find any case in which there is something better.

This problem is migrated from math.se , no advances were made.

Could someone point me to a more general family of problems or theory of this type?

Best Regards.

Comment: It is easy to find examples in which different constructions exist, for example if we consider a $2\times 2$ grid and remove the bottom right corner we can find another construction with $2$ diagonal lines. But I haven't been able to find a construction with less lines.

Comment: There are also the diagonal lines for some regular configurations (I'm thinking of part of a square grid).  I suspect an inductive proof may work to show n+m-1 is minimum: if more than m points are on a line, then it must be a red line, and now remove that red line from the set.  Gerhard "Follow This Line Of Reasoning" Paseman, 2017.06.09.

Comment: yeah thanks, I tried that but I reached an impasse, the bound of no more than $m$ points on a line seems too weak. You mean $n+m-2$ right?

Comment: I am unsure what the correct reasoning is. I meant m, but I could be wrong; I meant just to give the form of part of the argument.  Can you prove the result for small values of m?  Gerhard "Hoping For Some Inductive Magic" Paseman, 2017.06.09.

Comment: Oh, I'll try for small cases, good suggestion!

Comment: Oh, number of lines. Yes, I wrote n+m-1 instead of n+m-2.  Gerhard "Mind Is Somewhere Else Today" Paseman, 2017.06.09.

Comment: http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2007_IMO_Problems/Problem_6 https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-solve-the-IMOs-2007-Problem-6-listed-in-details I think I might have read about this on someone's blog on the Combinatorial Nullstellensatz.

Comment: Here is the copy to the MSE clone. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315092/family-of-coloring-lines-and-their-crossing-points#comment4764366_2315092

Comment: @DouglasZare does the solution to that problem pass over to this one?

Comment: It covers the case that the lines in each family are parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very nice paper "Cayley-Bacharach theorems and conjectures" by David Eisenbud, Mark Green, and Joe Harris (http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1996-33-03/S0273-0979-96-00666-0/home.html) gives an introduction to some related theory, including in particular a theorem which they number Theorem CB4: If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two plane curves of degrees $d$ and $e$ meeting at $de$ distinct points, and if $C$ is any curve of degree $d+e-3$ containing all but one of the intersection points of $X_1$ and $X_2$, then $C$ contains all of the intersection points.

In particular, if any collection of $m+n-3$ lines covers $mn-1$ of the intersection points of the red and blue lines, then they have to cover all $mn$ intersection points (it's impossible to cover $mn-1$ and miss $1$, with $m+n-3$ or fewer lines). This shows that $m+n-2$ is the least number of lines that can cover $mn-1$ of the points and miss $1$.

Credit: I couldn't for the life of me dredge up the memory of "Cayley-Bacharach" until I read Douglas Zare's answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much, this all looks very interesting. I once saw David in person but I didn't know any of his maths at the time :( .

Comment: I'm still hoping someone posts a more elementary solution.... :-)

Comment: @Zach Teitler: I think the special case of an evenly spaced $3$d grid is viewed as one of the toughest recent IMO problems. The $3$x$3$ case might not need the full Cayley-Bacharach theorem, but it does require Pappus's theorem. There are incidence geometries where Pappus's theorem does not hold, and where there are $3$x$3$ counterexamples. These narrow the possibilities for an easy solution.

Comment: I can still hope! :-) But, right, it seems like a faint hope.

Answer (score 4):

[Problem 6 from the 2007 IMO](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2007_IMO_Problems/Problem_6) is related. That problem was to determine the least number of hyperplanes needed to cover $\{0,1,...,n\}^3 \setminus \{(0,0,0)\}$, and the answer is $3n$. In general, the least number of hyperplanes needed to cover the lattice points in $\prod_{i=1}^k \{0,1,...,a_i\} \setminus \{\vec{0} \}$ is $\prod_{i=1}^k a_i$. This is an easy consequence of a deep result, the [Combinatorial Nullstellensatz](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/null2.pdf), which says that if $x_1^{e_1}...x_k^{e_k}$ is a term of highest degree of a polynomial $P$, and $S = \prod_{i=1}^k S_i,|S_i|=e_i$, then $P$ is nonzero at some point of $S$. This covers the case that the lines in each family are parallel (not just an evenly spaced grid).

For non-parallel lines, I don't know the answer in general. The $3\times 3$ case is covered by the [Cayley-Bacharach Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Bacharach_theorem), that if two cubic curves intersect in $9$ points, then if another conic passes through $8$ of those it must pass through the $9$th. The union of three lines is a cubic curve. So, the red lines and blue lines are two cubics intersecting in $9$ points, and if we have $3$ lines through $8$ of those points then they define another cubic which must include the last point.